# How do you delete empty lines from a textfile

Tags: vb.net, linq, text

I am trying to delete empty lines from a textfile using vb.net. This is an example of what I have tried so far however it is not working as expected:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim CountDeleted = 0
    Dim TextString As String

    For Each Line As String In lines
        TextString = lines(i)
        If TextString.Trim = "" Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
            CountDeleted += 1
        End If
        i += 1
    Next Line
```

This is an example of the data within a textfile that I would like to remove the lines from:

```
BUSINESS_UNIT|PO_ID|LINE_NBR|CANCEL_STATUS|

A

B
C
```

Required output:

```
BUSINESS_UNIT|PO_ID|LINE_NBR|CANCEL_STATUS|    
A
B
C
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the problem is some sort of skipping or do you get an exception?

Comment: What variable type is lines?  Also, what results do you get from the code you have?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the error that I had however it was the run time exception that was answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all the blank lines is just one line of code with linq

```
 Dim nonBlank = lines.Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
```

Counting the removed is just a difference between elements in the two lists

```
Dim CountDeleted = lines.Count - nonBlank.Count
```

Your code will trigger a runtime exception because you are removing an item from the same collection that you enumerate with the For Each loop.
You could switch to an old fashioned For Next loop but be careful to start from the end of the collection and examine the strings toward the beginning of the collection.

```
For i = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step - 1
    TextString = lines(i)
    If string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() Then
        lines.RemoveAt(i)
        CountDeleted += 1
    End If
Next
```

This backward loop is required because when you remove an item from the collection the total items count decrease and the items following the current index will slide one position. A normal (forward) loop will skip to examine the item following the one deleted.

Comment: I like this approach, very clean.  But if this code would work, then it seems like the original code would also work (albeit a bit clumsily).  I think something else is going on.

Comment: You haven't told us what is the error in your original code, but looking at it, you are removing items from the collection that you are enumerating with the for each. And this triggers always a runtime error. The above version instead builds a new enumerable with only the items that pass the condition. Of course this means that my version requires more memory but this should not be a problem unless your lines collection is really big.

Comment: I'm not the OP  :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have hit the nail on the head in your answer. The error I was receiving was related to iterating through the loop and removing indexes. I then had an error relating to an index that did not exist. I thought that I could update the for next loop manually and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all WhiteSpace strings from `List(Of String)`:

```
lines.RemoveAll(addressOf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
```

To remove all WhiteSpace lines from a text file:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path), "(?m)^\s+^", ""))
```